# FinalSize in ArrangeOverride is coming wrong

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, panel

I'm doing a custom panel, based(heriting) the WrapPanel.
I'm doing this because some UserControls I'm using in the WrapPanel don't wrap because they are able to use an "infinite" width, so a WrapPanel with a vertical orientation will never wrap.

I wanted to do one WrapPanel that ignore the width of the elements when having orientation = Vertical, and ignore the height of the elements when having an orientation = Horizontal.

Currently I've the following code:

```
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
{
    int numberOfColumns, numberOfRows;
    UIElement uiElement = InternalChildren.OfType<UIElement>().First();
    if (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
    {
        double desiredWidth = uiElement.DesiredSize.Width;
        numberOfColumns = (int)Math.Round(finalSize.Width / desiredWidth);
        numberOfRows = (int)Math.Ceiling(InternalChildren.Count / (double)numberOfColumns);
    }
    else
    {
        double desiredHeight = uiElement.DesiredSize.Height;
        numberOfRows = (int)Math.Round(finalSize.Height / desiredHeight);
        numberOfColumns = (int)Math.Ceiling(InternalChildren.Count / (double)numberOfRows);
    }
    int row = 0, column = 0;
    Size elementSize = new Size(Math.Floor(finalSize.Width / numberOfColumns), Math.Floor(finalSize.Height / numberOfRows));
    foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
    {
        child.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(row * elementSize.Width, column * elementSize.Height), elementSize));
        if (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
        {
            column++;
            if (column >= numberOfColumns)
            {
                column = 0;
                row++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            row++;
            if (row >= numberOfRows)
            {
                row = 0;
                column++;
            }
        }
    }
    return finalSize;
}
```

The issue is that the `finalSize` that I receives is bigger than the "ActualSize" of the component(Width 2x the actualSize in fact).

What did I miss?

Comment: You can't just set the standard WrapPanel's `ItemWidth` or `ItemHeight` property?

Comment: @Clemens unfortunately not, two reasons: the width/height will change when the window size changes, and currently we don't know what kind of items we have inside(used as Panel template in a ItemsControl )